# Removing ALL Duplicates Row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am looking to find out how I can remove ALL duplicate rows (when duplicates exist in the first column) using a VBA macro.

Currently Excel macros delete all duplicate instances EXCEPT for the first instance, which is totally not what I want. I want absolute removal.

Comment: Fantastic news. What did you try ?

Comment: Try my [Duplicate Master Addin](http://sdrv.ms/18pQI6C). Works accross sheets if needed, handles case sensitivity, white spaces and regexp matching.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37358305/6201755

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter solution done for quick morning training:

```
Sub quicker_Option()

    Dim toDel(), i As Long
    Dim RNG As Range, Cell As Long
    Set RNG = Range("a1:a19") 'set your range here

    For Cell = 1 To RNG.Cells.Count
        If Application.CountIf(RNG, RNG(Cell)) > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve toDel(i)
            toDel(i) = RNG(Cell).Address
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    For i = UBound(toDel) To LBound(toDel) Step -1
        Range(toDel(i)).EntireRow.Delete

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting! I've never thought of using an array to store cells address. (+1) for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Store the first instance's cell for later deleting.
Then go deleting duplicates until the end.

```
Dim F as integer, S as integer   'indices for First and Second cells to be compared
Dim Deleted as boolean         'indicates if second line was deleted
Dim First as Range, Second as Range   'First and second cells to be compared
Dim Start as string                   'Indicates the position of the first cell's start

Start = "A1"   'can be as you like
Set First = Sheet1.Range(Start)  'Sets the start cell

F = 0          '
Do While First.Value <> ""    'loop while sheet contains data in the column 
    S = F + 1                 'second cell is at least 1 cell below first cell
    Deleted = false           'no second cell was deleted yet
    Set Second = First.Offset(S,0)      'second cell is an offset of the first cell

    Do While Second.Value <> ""       'loop while second cell is in sheet's range with data
        if Second.Value = First.Value then    'if values are duplicade
            Second.EntreRow.Delete              'delete second cell
            Deleted = true                       'stores deleted information
        else                                'if not, second cell index goes next
            S = S + 1;
        end if

        Set Second = First.Offset(S, 0)      'sets second cell again (if deleted, same position, if not deleted, next position
    Loop

    if Deleted then         'if deleted, should delete first cell as well
        First.EntireRow.Delete
    else
        F = F + 1           'if no duplicates found, first cell goes next
    end if

    Set First = Sheet1.Range(Start).Offset(F,0)     'sets first cell again (if deleted, same position, if not, next)
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to create an Auto reconciliation of general ledger control accounts where if any cell with equal value but opposite sign is cut to sheet 2; hence left with only reconciliation item.

the code:

```
sub    autoRecs()
dim i as long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.StatusBar = True
Dim i As Long
Cells(5, 6).Select
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
x = ActiveCell.Row
y = x + 1
Do Until Cells(x, 6) = 0
Do Until Cells(y, 6) = 0
Application.StatusBar = "Hey Relax! You can rely on me......"
If Cells(x, 6) = Cells(y, 6) * -1 Then
Cells(x, 6).EntireRow.Cut (Worksheets(2).Cells(x, 6).EntireRow)
Cells(y, 6).EntireRow.Cut (Worksheets(2).Cells(y, 6).EntireRow)
Cells(x, 6).Value = "=today()"
Cells(y, 6).Value = "=today()"
Else
y = y + 1
End If
Loop
x = x + 1
y = x + 1
Loop
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Sub deleteBlankCells()`this is to delete unnecessary cells after run the above macro`
Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Select
For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 
Application.StatusBar = "OOH! I'm cleaning all the blanks for you....."
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next i
Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to work with arrays within VBA, so here is an example.

- Assume the data represents the currentregion around A1, but that is easily changed
- Read the source data into an array
- Check each item in column one to ensure it is unique (countif of that item = 1)
- If unique, add the corresponding row number to a Collection
- Use the size of th collection and the number of columns to Dim a results array.
- Cycle through the collection, writing the corresponding rows to a results array.
- Write the results array to the worksheet.

As written, the results are placed to the right of the source data, but could also replace it, or be placed on a different sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicatedRows()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim colUniqueRows As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'assume data starts in A1 and represented by currentregion
Set rSrc = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
vSrc = rSrc

Set rRes = rSrc.Offset(0, UBound(vSrc, 2) + 2)

'get collection of non-duplicated rows
Set colUniqueRows = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rSrc.Columns(1), vSrc(I, 1)) = 1 Then _
        colUniqueRows.Add I
Next I

'Make up results array
ReDim vRes(1 To colUniqueRows.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 1)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
        vRes(I, J) = vSrc(colUniqueRows(I), J)
    Next J
Next I

rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes)) = vRes

End Sub
```