# Remove ALL duplicates from column A in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a macro that can remove ALL duplicates from column A.

Input:

```
John
Jimmy
Brenda
Brenda
Tom
Tom
Todd
```

Output:

```
John
Jimmy
Todd
```

I am working with a large set of data, and Excel isn't cooperating. Can't seem to find a solution online that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into the Remove Duplicate function on the data tab?  Excel already has a function that does this.

Comment: @ScottCraner I would not vote her down for this. Excel 2003 and earlier does not have this Remove Duplicates function. So it is a valid question. I edited the post to make this clear.

Comment: @ib11 First I am not the one who down voted, I would not have done so till I had heard from the OP.  Second where do you get that the OP is using 2003, I see where **YOU** assumed as much and **YOU** put that in the question.  I was waiting for an answer to a question.  It is not really appropriate for editors to put their own interpretations on other peoples questions, unless you have proof that the OP is truly using 2003, you are assuming that they do.  That is as bad as assuming that they just did not know of remove duplicates.  Personally unless you have proof I would rollback the edit.

Comment: @ScottCraner Actually, it just dawned on me that the OP's output is not only remove the repeated (duplicate) but wants to remove what is duplicated: **both**. Different approach. And now, **that** is not an excel function and needs a VBA macro.

Comment: @ib11 then it does not matter the excel version.  I have removed all version specific tags and verbiage that was not in the Original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to **de-duplicate** your list, that is make sure you only have ONE item left of each, you can to this:

In Excel 2007 and above you have a Remove Duplicates in the Data menu, which will do it for you.

In Excel 2003 and earlier you can use the Advanced Filter in the Data/Filter menu:

[image]

And then copy-paste the results in a new sheet.

You can see the full procedure [here.](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s177/how_to_remove_duplicates_from_a_list_in_excel_pt2.htm)

Otherwise it is a tedious macro to write (a recursive loop to check if the value exist in the set). It can be done, but do you really need it?

But if you want to actually delete all entries that are the same then using @Eoins's macro will do the job, but a bit modified as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDuplicate()
    Dim x, Y As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim myCell As String
    LastRow = Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        myCell = Range("A" & x).Text
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & x), myCell) > 1 Then
            For Y = x To 1 Step -1
                If Range("A" & Y).Text = myCell Then
                    Range("A" & Y).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next Y
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: You can still use the advanced filter tdo eliminate all duplicated items.  Just use a formula criteria that checks that the Count for each entry is exactly `1`

Comment: Thank you very much! The macro worked wonderfully. I have tried all options on Excel, including your suggestion of Advanced Filter, but it took way too long and Excel kept crashing on me trying to run over 500,000 rows. You are awesome!

Comment: @BrendaTonLinkous You are very welcome. Was a smart question. As you see, it promted quite some activity.

Comment: @BrendaTonLinkous I modified one more point, which is that it detects the last row independently how many rows you have (before it was arbitrarily set, now it is the absolute last row).

Answer (score 2):

As your request is for a macro, please try this:

Excel 2007+

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates
```

Here is your option for Excel 2003

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeletDuplicate()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & x), Range("A" & x).Text) > 1 Then
        Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Delete
      End If
  Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that this only works for Excel 2007 and above, see comment under the question, so please include this in your answer.

Comment: BTW, your solution on looping backwards is a smart approach, upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks for sending this over, this solution does the same as Remove Duplicates function, which isn't what I was looking for. It keeps the unique values, which I was looking to delete all duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive loop just in case you want it :)

It's actually 2 procedures, the first one sorts the list and the second one removes duplicates

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
'--SORT A 1D ARRAY NUMERICALLY-ALPHABETICALLY(TAKEN FROM StackOverflow)
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Public Sub QuickSort(vArray As Variant, inLow As Long, inHi As Long)

        Dim pivot   As Variant
        Dim tmpSwap As Variant
        Dim tmpLow  As Long
        Dim tmpHi   As Long

        tmpLow = inLow
        tmpHi = inHi

        pivot = vArray((inLow + inHi) \ 2)

        While (tmpLow <= tmpHi)

            While (vArray(tmpLow) < pivot And tmpLow < inHi)
                tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
            Wend

            While (pivot < vArray(tmpHi) And tmpHi > inLow)
                tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
            Wend

            If (tmpLow <= tmpHi) Then
                tmpSwap = vArray(tmpLow)
                vArray(tmpLow) = vArray(tmpHi)
                vArray(tmpHi) = tmpSwap
                tmpLow = tmpLow + 1
                tmpHi = tmpHi - 1
            End If

        Wend

        If (inLow < tmpHi) Then QuickSort vArray, inLow, tmpHi
        If (tmpLow < inHi) Then QuickSort vArray, tmpLow, inHi

    End Sub


'---------------------------------------
'--REMOVE DUPLICATES AND BLANKS FROM SORTED 1D ARRAY
'---------------------------------------
Public Function RemoveDuplicatesBlanks_1DSorted(Arr As Variant) As Variant

    Dim i As Long, iMin As Long, iMax As Long, Cnt As Long
    Dim TArr As Variant, TArr2() As Variant

    TArr = Arr
    iMin = LBound(TArr)
    iMax = UBound(TArr)

    i = iMin

    Do While i <= iMax
        If TArr(i) = vbNullString Then
            Cnt = Cnt + 1
        ElseIf i < iMax Then
            If TArr(i) = TArr(i + 1) Then
                TArr(i) = Empty
                Cnt = Cnt + 1
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ReDim TArr2(iMin To (iMax - Cnt))

    Cnt = iMin

    For i = iMin To iMax
        If Not TArr(i) = vbNullString Then
            TArr2(Cnt) = TArr(i)
            Cnt = Cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i

    RemoveDuplicatesBlanks_1DSorted = TArr2
End Function
```

The way these are setup you would use them like this.....

```
QuickSort MyArray, LBound(MyArray), UBOUND(MyArray)

MyArray = RemoveDuplicatesBlanks_1DSorted(MyArray)
```

These work only for 1 dimensional arrays, I also have them for 2 dimensional arrays if you need those.

I've used these many times and they are very fast, a lot faster than most methods so if you have large lists its worth using these methods.

----ADDITIONAL INFORMATION----

The ExtractArrayColumn function is beneath this code....This code here is how you would use all these procedures

```
Private sub RemoveDuplicate()
    Dim MyRangeArray As Variant, MyArray As Variant
    MyRangeArray = Range("A1:A100").Value

    MyArray = ExtractArrayColumn(MyRAngeArray,1)

    QuickSort MyArray, LBound(MyArray), UBOUND(MyArray)

    MyArray = RemoveDuplicatesBlanks_1DSorted(MyArray)

    Range("A1:A100").Value = MyArray
End Sub







Public Function ExtractArrayColumn(Array_Obj As Variant, Column_Index As Long) As Variant
    Dim TArr() As Variant
    Dim L1 As Long, H1 As Long
    Dim i As Long

    L1 = LBound(Array_Obj, 1)
    H1 = UBound(Array_Obj, 1)

    ReDim TArr(L1 To H1)

    For i = L1 To H1
        TArr(i) = Array_Obj(i, Column_Index)
    Next i

    ExtractArrayColumn = TArr
End Function
```

Comment: Your code is useful for arrays, but please make it usable for the OP's question which is how to remove duplicates from an Excel sheet, column A, specifically. Also note that you don't necessarily want to sort the column! I mean, please correct your answer so it answers the question.

Comment: Breaking the order of the list implies that order is not important...... the sort is required for this duplicate removal algorithm, and if the OP needs further help with other aspects then all they need to do is ask.. I Will updat the answer to include all necessary code to make this work.....

Comment: :), its probably a little overkill but at least it should do the job.

Comment: It is nice. But you know what, after reading her post the 5th time, I finally understood what she meant. See my comment on the OP and the code I posted to my answer.

Comment: Ha, i missed that too, might just be a mistake if not then everyone failed to help haha.

Comment: Lol no wonder, it took me 5 read! But my answer does have the code, so if she comes back, she will have it ;-)